Text & formula in one cell - can't get the number to be currency?
I currently have text and a formula in one cell, I'm struggling to make the formula display as currency. I've changed the cell to 'currency' but it is just showing as a number without a currency sign or commas etc. Help please!

What do you mean by "text and a formula" in a cell? You can input a value or a formula in a cell. It may be helpful to upload a screencap to http://imgur.com and link to it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm guessing the reasn why using the number formatting is not resulting in any visual changes is that the cell contains text that looks like a number.

I think this helps ="Your Text "&TEXT(calculation,"$ #,##0.00")

I agree with P.b. You may add a "Text" function in your formula.
